# Monoid instance for A => A in Cats

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monoids, scala-cats

Functions `A => A` are monoid with `identity` as `empty` and composition as `combine`. Unfortunately I did not find it in `cats` library. Does the library provide a monoid instance for these functions ?

What about `A => M[A]`, where `M` is a monad or applicative ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cats has a Monoid instance of `A => A` in [instances/function.scala](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/f6ef91e7bd920138226c00862de45b841e59c3ca/core/src/main/scala/cats/instances/function.scala#L92).

`A => M[A]` for a Monad `M` seams to form form a Monoid with `a => M.pure(a)` as `empty` the following `combine` op:

```
def compose(f1 = A => M[A], f2 = A => M[A]): A => M[A] =
  a => f1(a).flatMap { e => f2(e) }
```

This does does not apeart to be implemented in the library.
Proof of Monoid laws left as an exersise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is `X => A[X]`, where is `A` is Applicative, a monoid ?

Comment: A monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors, what's the problem?

Comment: @Michael Can you write a `combine` op without `flatMap`?

Comment: Maybe not. I should think about it.